# getting error on when editting Word file in Word Online through my external SharePoint URL

Tags: office-online-server

This is my setup.

- Server1: SharePoint Front end with distributed cache
- Server2: SharePoint Search and application
- Server3: Office Online Server

I have a SharePoint web application with a default zone and extended this web application with an internet zone.
The default zone authentication is configured with Active Directory.
The internet zone authentication is configured with our Custom Membershipprovider.

IIS bindings on the default zone

1. Internal URL (http) sharepointinternalurl
2. Internal URL (https) sharepointinternalurl  (uses wildcard certificate)

The friendly name of the wildcard is without asterix.

IIS bindings on internet zone

1. External URL (HTTP) sharepointexternalurl
2. External URL (HTTPS) sharepointexternalurl  (uses same wildcard certificate)

AAM setup in SharePoint

1. Internal URL:(https)sharepointinternalurl, Zone:Default, Public URL:(https)sharepointinternalurl
2. Internal URL:(http)sharepointinternalurl, Zone:Default, Public URL:(http)sharepointinternalurl
3. External URL:(https)sharepointexternalurl, Zone:Internet, Public URL:(https)sharepointexternalurl
4. External URL:(http)sharepointexternalurl, Zone:Internet, Public URL:(http)sharepointexternalurl

in both of the web.configs (internal and external zone) in IIS I use redirect rules to redirect http requests to https.

```
  <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" ignoreCase="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Office Online Server farm configuration

```
FarmOU                                       :
InternalURL                                  : https://officeonlineserver.nl/
ExternalURL                                  : https://officeonlineserver.nl/
AllowHTTP                                    : False
AllowOutboundHttp                            : False
SSLOffloaded                                 : False
CertificateName                              : <friendlyname of certificate>
S2SCertificateName                           :
EditingEnabled                               : True
LogLocation                                  : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Data\Logs\ULS
LogRetentionInDays                           : 7
LogVerbosity                                 :
Proxy                                        :
CacheLocation                                : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Working\d
MaxMemoryCacheSizeInMB                       : 75
DocumentInfoCacheSize                        : 5000
CacheSizeInGB                                : 15
ClipartEnabled                               : False
OnlinePictureEnabled                         : False
OnlineVideoEnabled                           : False
TranslationEnabled                           : False
MaxTranslationCharacterCount                 : 125000
TranslationServiceAppId                      :
TranslationServiceAddress                    :
RenderingLocalCacheLocation                  : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\OfficeWebApps\Working\waccache
RecycleActiveProcessCount                    : 5
AllowCEIP                                    : False
OfficeAddinEnabled                           : False
ExcelRequestDurationMax                      : 300
ExcelSessionTimeout                          : 450
ExcelWorkbookSizeMax                         : 30
ExcelPrivateBytesMax                         : -1
ExcelConnectionLifetime                      : 1800
ExcelExternalDataCacheLifetime               : 300
ExcelAllowExternalData                       : True
ExcelUseEffectiveUserName                    : False
ExcelWarnOnDataRefresh                       : True
ExcelUdfsAllowed                             : False
ExcelMemoryCacheThreshold                    : 85
ExcelUnusedObjectAgeMax                      : -1
ExcelCachingUnusedFiles                      : True
ExcelAbortOnRefreshOnOpenFail                : True
ExcelEnableCrossForestKerberosAuthentication : False
ExcelAutomaticVolatileFunctionCacheLifeTime  : 300
ExcelConcurrentDataRequestsPerSessionMax     : 5
ExcelDefaultWorkbookCalcMode                 : File
ExcelRestExternalDataEnabled                 : True
ExcelChartAndImageSizeMax                    : 1
OpenFromUrlEnabled                           : False
OpenFromUncEnabled                           : True
OpenFromUrlThrottlingEnabled                 : True
PicturePasteDisabled                         : True
RemovePersonalInformationFromLogs            : False
AllowHttpSecureStoreConnections              : False
Machines                               : <Netbios name of Office Online Server>
```

SPWOPI settings in SharePoint

For all the documents I have set up https://officeonlineserver.nl/ as binding
and the WopiZone is configured as external-https
See example Word document when I type `get-spwopibinding`

```
Application     : Word
Extension       : DOCX
ProgId          :
Action          : preloadview
IsDefaultAction : False
ServerName      : officeonlineserver.nl
WopiZone        : external-https
```

`get-spwopizone` shows `external-https`

I didn't allow HTTP when setting up the SpWopi in SharePoint.

When I open and edit documents while I am logged in my internal SharePoint URL (https://sharepointinternalurl), everything works fine.
I can open and edit Excel, PowerPoint and Word files and open PDF files.

When I open and edit documents while I am logged in my external SharePoint URL (https://sharepointexternalurl) not everything works fine.
I can open and edit Excel files.
I can open PDF files.
I can open Word files but I get an error when I try to edit Word files.
I cannot open/edit PowerPoint files. I get a different error than editing Word files.

About the PowerPoint files, it is not that important for me, but I need to fix the issue about editing Word files.
I already tried many things.
Some of the steps to fix this issue I will sum up.

1. I deleted the rewrite rules in both of my SharePoint web.configs.
2. I deleted the HTTP bindings in IIS in both of my web applications I deleted the HTTP AAM for both of my zones in SharePoint.

I look up in ULS logging on the Office Online Server and I saw this error related to the correlation id when trying to edit Word files.

> Exception occurred while TransformDocumentToBox4Internal, logging
>   before bailing out. 
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.EnvironmentAdapters.FileUnknownException:
>   WOPI 404 ---> System.Web.HttpException: FileNotFound
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.AddHostResponseDataAndThrow(Exception
>   exception, HttpRequestAsyncResult result) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End() at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.CobaltExecutionHelper.ExecuteCobaltRequest(BaseDocument
>   doc, HostMetadata hostMetadata, String relativePath, Stream
>   requestStream, String rootOperation, String& newDocumentFileRep) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.CobaltCellStorageRequestProcessor.ExecuteCellStorageRequestForEnvironment(String
>   relativePath, Stream requestStream, Guid partition,
>   ILocalCobaltRequestContext lcRequestContext, String expectedLock,
>   String clientId, String rootOperation, String& newDocumentFileRep) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.CobaltEndpointOnCellStorageRequestProcessor.ExecuteRequestBatch(RequestBatch
>   requestBatch) at Cobalt.Roundtrip.Execute() at
>   Cobalt.DataElementGraphOnEndpoint2.Download(Boolean full) at
>   Cobalt.DataElementGraphOnEndpoint2.OnIncrementalRefresh(Boolean
>   prefetchTopology) at Cobalt.CellGraph.RefreshDataElementGraph() at
>   Cobalt.CellGraph.Load(Boolean allowSchemaChange, CellGraphLoadMetrics
>   metrics, Boolean refreshDataElementGraph) at
>   Cobalt.GenericFda.Refresh(Boolean onlyIfFirstTime, Boolean
>   allowSchemaChange, Boolean refreshDataElementGraph) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.StreamFromPartition.GetReadStream(ExtendedGuid
>   streamId, Byte[]& serializedKnowledge) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Coauthoring.PartitionManager.GetMemoryStream(ExtendedGuid
>   streamId, Func`1 streamFactory, Byte[]& knowledge) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.WordLoadSaveUtils.GetDocumentStream(BaseDocument
>   baseDoc, IContentPartitionManager contentPartitionManager,
>   IPartitionManager convertedPartitionManager, IMainStorage mainStorage,
>   String sessionId, Boolean needsConversion, Boolean isSaveOperation,
>   Boolean returnOriginalStream) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.WordLoadSaveUtils.GetDocumentStreamForLoad(BaseDocument
>   baseDoc, IContentPartitionManager contentPartitionManager,
>   IMainStorage mainStorage, String sessionId, Boolean needsConversion,
>   Boolean returnOriginalStream) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__34.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__33.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__32.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__31.MoveNext():
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.AddHostResponseDataAndThrow(Exception
>   exception, HttpRequestAsyncResult result) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiTalky.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Common.WopiDocument.LogAndThrowWireException(HttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result, HttpRequestAsyncException delayedException) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Common.HttpRequestAsync.End() at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.CobaltExecutionHelper.ExecuteCobaltRequest(BaseDocument
>   doc, HostMetadata hostMetadata, String relativePath, Stream
>   requestStream, String rootOperation, String& newDocumentFileRep) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.CobaltCellStorageRequestProcessor.ExecuteCellStorageRequestForEnvironment(String
>   relativePath, Stream requestStream, Guid partition,
>   ILocalCobaltRequestContext lcRequestContext, String expectedLock,
>   String clientId, String rootOperation, String& newDocumentFileRep) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.CobaltEndpointOnCellStorageRequestProcessor.ExecuteRequestBatch(RequestBatch
>   requestBatch) at Cobalt.Roundtrip.Execute() at
>   Cobalt.DataElementGraphOnEndpoint2.Download(Boolean full) at
>   Cobalt.DataElementGraphOnEndpoint2.OnIncrementalRefresh(Boolean
>   prefetchTopology) at Cobalt.CellGraph.RefreshDataElementGraph() at
>   Cobalt.CellGraph.Load(Boolean allowSchemaChange, CellGraphLoadMetrics
>   metrics, Boolean refreshDataElementGraph) at
>   Cobalt.GenericFda.Refresh(Boolean onlyIfFirstTime, Boolean
>   allowSchemaChange, Boolean refreshDataElementGraph) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.CellStorage.StreamFromPartition.GetReadStream(ExtendedGuid
>   streamId, Byte[]& serializedKnowledge) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Coauthoring.PartitionManager.GetMemoryStream(ExtendedGuid
>   streamId, Func`1 streamFactory, Byte[]& knowledge) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.WordLoadSaveUtils.GetDocumentStream(BaseDocument
>   baseDoc, IContentPartitionManager contentPartitionManager,
>   IPartitionManager convertedPartitionManager, IMainStorage mainStorage,
>   String sessionId, Boolean needsConversion, Boolean isSaveOperation,
>   Boolean returnOriginalStream) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.WordLoadSaveUtils.GetDocumentStreamForLoad(BaseDocument
>   baseDoc, IContentPartitionManager contentPartitionManager,
>   IMainStorage mainStorage, String sessionId, Boolean needsConversion,
>   Boolean returnOriginalStream) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__34.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__33.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__32.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Office.Web.Box4.WordCompanion.TransformDocumentToBox4Operation.d__31.MoveNext()

Comment: Have you tried re-moving and re-adding binding for OWA server?

Comment: Sorry, I see this message now.
I totally removed the OfficeWebAppsMachine and rebuild it because of the latest Office Online Server ISO and update.
I removed the Office Online Server software from the server and installed the latest ISO build with the latest update.
I used this command to remove: Remove-OfficeWebAppsMachine
Unfortunately the problem is not fixed.
Any suggestion?

Comment: About removing and re-adding the binding, I have also run this command from the SharePoint Shell.
Remove-SPWOPIBinding -All
New-SPWOPIBinding -ServerName <office online url wihout http:// or https://>
Set-SPWOPIZone -zone "external-https"
iisreset /noforce

The problem still exist with editing Word and Powerpoint files from the external web application (logging in through forms based)